# Possible number of codes for license plate

Tags: combinatorics

1. A country issues license plates that consist of just one number ( $0$ through $9$, inclusive ) and five letters, selected from a $25$-letter alphabet, while the other five alphabets are ignored.
2. Repeats are permitted.
3. However, there is only one five-letter combination that is not allowed to appear on license plates.

How many allowable license plate combinations exist ?.

I found this in an website, which is showing answer as
$10 \times 25 \times 25 \times 25\times 25\times 25 - 10 \times 1 \times 1 \times1\times1\times 1$. But, I don't see from the question that the numbers will come first. In this case, shouldn't I multiply the whole outcome by $6C1$, which a place selection for numbers ?.

Comment: What's the meaning of "while the other five alphabets are ignored", and what difference does it make with regards to the question at hand (i.e., why do we need to know about alphabet letters that are ignored)??? In addition, the word "However" doesn't make any sense in the context.

Comment: If the license plate has five letters, why do you/they get $25^3$, and not $25^5$?

Comment: corrected, thanks. but my question is, why should I consider the first place as number? why not any number or any alphabet?

Comment: Stuff you find on websites may not have been edited as carefully as stuff you find in books (and even in books, one occasionally finds typographical errors, ambiguous phrases, etc.). Presumably, whoever wrote up the answer interpreted the question as "one number *followed by* five letters". If you don't makethat interpretation, then, yes, you need to multiply by 6. Although even then the phrase "one five-letter combination" is ambiguous. "combination" usually means order doesn't matter, but it's not clear what it means here. Have you given the exact wording?

Comment: Yes, I presume, wording is exactly as it was there, that made me confused as well. Unfortunately, it was a renowned GRE prep site, and they solved it there, which is why I got so confused. I also agree with you they wanted to ask "one number followed by five letters" and the wording of "five-letter combination  that is not allowed" should have been "a specific 5-letter arrangement is not allowed".